# pixel perfect iOS app design conflicting with auto layout

Tags: iphone, layout, pixel

Client has provided me with PSD designs for iPhone 5. When i am trying to implement the same I've found that apple follows point convention instead of pixel which is roughly like 1 point = 2 pixel for retina display. 
When i am trying to implement those design on Xcode it looks weird though. Say for instance the top navigation bar is 92 px (as per client). I made it half and implemented 46 pts on Xcode. It matches up when i compare the screenshot from the iPhone 5 with the PSD's. But as soon as i run it on iPhone 6 real device it looks pretty much tiny. 
How to solve this issue and how am i suppose to have same aspect ratio on all screens considering I was putting constraints as 0,0,0 left,top,right and 46 pts height.

Comment: ByDefault navigation bar size is 66 may be your issue is coming due to navigation bar size - Cross Check again .

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it is a custom navigation bar. basically it is a UIView only having buttons. update is i did the same thing via disabling auto layout and size class and things work fine now. they automatically resize as desired. i wonder if the same could be achieved  via auto-layout it is going to be excellent